# MockHttpServletRequest mc = new MockHttpServletRequest() = >Unknown type "org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest"

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 4.3.20 and have a MockHttpServletRequest to create requests and call different controller. The code act as a wrapper to all the controllers. I am getting error: MockHttpServletRequest mc = new MockHttpServletRequest() = >Unknown type "org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest"<

Earlier with Spring 3 it was working fine, but with Spring 4 I am getting the mentioned error. I replaced spring-mock with spring-test of 4.3.20 and getting this issue

```
MockHttpServletRequest mc = new MockHttpServletRequest();
                        mc.setSession(request.getSession());
                        mc.addPreferredLocale(RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request));
// Add all the parameters in mc.
```

This should work fine as with Spring 3 and spring-mock 2.0.8

Comment: Spring 3 and Spring Mock 2 are jars from different versions of Spring. Never mix versions of a framework (regardless of the framework).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("post", "requestMappingUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using spring-test as own library and renamed it.